# Why can't I change my MAC address to this address?

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, networkmanager

Why can't I spoof my wifi card's MAC address to `1F:2E:3D:4C:5B:6A`. Is that address invalid?

```
root@:~# ifconfig wlan0 down
root@:~# ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 1f:2e:3d:4c:5b:6a
SIOCSIFHWADDR: Cannot assign requested address
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in [this AskUbuntu question/answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423530/cant-change-my-mac-address-cant-assign-requested-address), a unicast MAC address' first octet (your `1f`) has to be *even*.

Since `1f` (31) is not even, you can't assign it.

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry for it. I'm new in here.

Comment: @user825347 No worries :-)